# R version 3.3.2, Windows 10: gstat package: Error in fitting a variogram model using 'fit.variogram' function

Tags: r, geospatial, gstat, covariogram

I am having some problem with `fit.variogram`  function of the `gstat` package.  My code, data, error message and `traceback()` message can be found below. Any suggestion to approach this problem would be appreciated.

```
library(gstat)
mydf<-as.data.frame(read.table("Sample_data.xlsx",header = TRUE,sep = 
",",na.strings = "EMPTY"))
coordinates(mydf) = ~x+y
c.vgm.exp<-variogram(z~1,data=mydf,cutoff=60000, width = 60000/15)
c.vgm.fit<-fit.variogram(c.vgm.exp,vgm(nugget=1000000,psill=6000000,model 
="Exp",range = 40000),fit.method = 7)
```

Data file can be obtained from:
https://gtvault-my.sharepoint.com/personal/srathore6_gatech_edu/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=0b5983d45c9544203a5081cd501c64de4&authkey=AYhC8_ZVvGFG18JHHWMgUa4&expiration=2017-12-01T19%3a45%3a23.000Z

Error Message:

```
c.vgm.fit<-fit.variogram(c.vgm.exp,vgm(nugget=1000000,psill=6000000,model 
="Exp",range = 40000),fit.method = 7)
Error in switch(model, exponential = fit.exponential(v.object, c0 = nugget,: 
EXPR must be a length 1 vector

traceback()
1: fit.variogram(c.vgm.exp, vgm(nugget = 1e+06, psill = 6e+06, model = 
"Exp", range = 40000), fit.method = 7)
```

Comment: I have tried rescaling the data by dividing x, y, and z by thousand, but that also did not help.